# Deleting user commands after reading the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to delete the message sent by the user as the command for example if the user commands
-say hello i want the bot to delete the message by the user and send a message saying the words user sent

I have written the basic thing but i want the way to delete the message user sent

```
client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, words):
    await ctx.send(words)
```

this is the code i have written till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

after your command code. I hope I was able to help you!